# Building a table of year and quarter combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a year and a quarter and I want to build a table lists a specific number of year and quarter combinations ending with the given year and quarter.

E.g.

```
**Input:** 
Year = 2018 
Quarter = 3 
NumRows = 4

**Output:** 
Year.....|Quarter
2018.....|3
2018.....|2
2018.....|1
2017.....|4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursive generation.

First you need to build a DATETIME object from the year and quarter.

```
DECLARE @Quarter INT = 3;
DECLARE @Year INT = 2018;
DECLARE @NumRows INT = 4;

DECLARE @initial_date DATETIME = DATEADD(quarter, @Quarter-1, DATEADD(year, @Year-1900, 0));
```

Then you can recursively generate the year & quarter combinations like this.

```
;WITH quarters AS (
    SELECT @initial_date AS [qdate]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(quarter, -1, [qdate])  AS [qdate]
    FROM quarters
    WHERE [qdate] > DATEADD(quarter, -1*(@NumRows-1), @initial_date)
)
SELECT DATEPART(year, qdate) as year, DATEPART(quarter, qdate) as quarter FROM quarters
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use cte recursive with some calculation

```
DECLARE @Year INT= 2018 
DECLARE @Quarter INT = 3 
DECLARE @NumRows INT= 10

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT (@Year - @NumRows/4) yr,
            4 - (@NumRows % 4) Quarter,
        @NumRows NumRows
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  yr + Quarter / 4, 
         CASE WHEN (Quarter + 1) % 4 = 0 THEN 4 
             ELSE (Quarter + 1) % 4 
         END,
        NumRows- 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE NumRows > 1
)
select yr,Quarter 
from cte
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3300f824ef952faf61d367a1b898823)

Comment: the result is wrong when `@NumRows` is greater than 4

Answer (score 1):

this uses a recursive cte

for

```
declare @year       int = 2018,
        @quarter    int = 3,
        @numrows    int = 6


; with rcte as
(
    select  n   = 1,
        yr  = @year,
        qtr = @quarter

    union all

    select  n   = n + 1,
            yr  = yr - (((qtr - 1 + 4 - 1) % 4 + 1) / 4),
            qtr = (qtr - 1 + 4 - 1) % 4 + 1
    from    rcte
    where   n   < @numrows
)
select  *
from    rcte
order by n

/* result:
n   yr      qtr
1   2018    3
2   2018    2
3   2018    1
4   2017    4
5   2017    3
6   2017    2
*/
```